# About a group of 5, why do you say "...a fourth..." about "the fourth one" but "...the fifth" when it comes to the fifth one?

Tags: grammar, articles, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC News, [Australia mushroom poisoning](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-66391325)

**Two Saturdays ago, five people sat down for a family meal in a tiny Australian town.
Within a week, three would be dead, a fourth fighting for life, and the fifth under investigation for potentially poisoning her guests with wild mushrooms.**

Why is it **"...a fourth...."** but **"....the fifth...."** when it comes to the fifth one? In other words, why does it use **"a"** with the fourth one, but **"the"** with the fifth one?

Is it because there can be more than one **"fourth"** but only one **"fifth"**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having accounted for the three who had died, and one more who was sick,  the identity of the last person is "determined", At that point there is only one person left, and hence  "the fifth".

The ordering is deliberate, the final person is contrasted with the other four as a perpetrator - Again this determines them relative to the others. Saying "the fourth" would have been correct, but by choosing "a fourth",  there is a sense in which this person is not particularly special, and could have been dead, except by luck.

Comment: As an example, had there been six people at the table it would have been "four would be dead, a fifth fighting for life, and the sixth under investigation"